# I have no money to buy a bed [with]

Tags: syntactic-analysis

### BACKGROUND

In this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48323/to-buy-a-bed-with-vs-to-play-a-ball-with), it was asked why it sounds better to omit 'with' in

> *I have no money to buy a bed (**with**).*

whereas 'with' sounds right in

> *I have no ball to play soccer **with**.*

Indeed, the 'with' feels redundant at best in

> *I have no money to buy a bed **with**.*

On the other hand, leaving out 'with' here would make it ungrammatical

> *I have no ball to play soccer.* (??)

This is not limited to 'soccer'

> *I have no ball to play.* (??)

Instead, it should be:

> *I have no ball to play **with**.*

As one of the answers in the quoted question says, it may be okay to use 'with which' as in:

> *I have no money **with which** to buy a bed.*

Given that the version without 'with which' sounds right, it might be argued that this version with 'with which' may be redundant and thus as unidiomatic as *I have no money to buy a bed with*. But native speakers seem to find the former grammatical.

Now, moving on to the finite relative clause, compare these:

> (1) *I have no money I can buy a bed.* (??)
>
> (2) *I have no money I can buy a bed **with**.*
>
> (3) *I have no money **with which** I can buy a bed.*

Here, it seems clear to me that 'with' cannot be omitted, unlike the infinitive relative clause.

### QUESTION

Therefore, I'd say that the idiomatic *I have no money to buy a bed* resisting *with* at the end is more of an exception in the sense that corresponding finite relative clauses do require 'with' either at the beginning or at the end of the clause, and that the corresponding infinitive clause with 'which' requires 'with'.

**What do you think triggers this exception?**

### EDIT

It may be worthwhile to note that the version with "with" is not ungrammatical:

> *I have no money to buy a bed **with**.*

Some native speakers might find this version more correct --  if not more common -- than the one lacking "with".

Comment: To me, "I have no money to buy a bed" suggests that *the money*, not you, would be doing the buying,  You'd like to buy a bed *with* money  -  that's where the 'with' comes in.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, so I don't judge what a native speaker feels is right or wrong. The version without 'with' was preferred to the one without by the person who submitted the quoted question, who I assumed was a native speaker. Moreover, those who responded to that quoted question, who, again, I assumed were native speakers, had NOT rejected such a preference itself. And now you, apparently another native speaker, come in and say that you disagree with all the others in terms of the acceptability of the version without 'with'?

Comment: Well, not exactly, @JK2.  I ran the different versions thru my head, and the ones with 'with' sounded best to me.  Then I tried to figure why, and came up with my *comment*.  It wasn't, and wasn't intended to be, a ruling, and I'm not actually disagreeing with the other opinions.

Comment: @JK2 I've re-read everything this morning, and I now can't hear anything wrong with "I have no money to buy a bed."

Comment: You probably have a copy of the 2002 *CGEL*, and if so, you might want to look at their sections related to *hollow clauses* and *infinitival relative clauses*.

Comment: @F.E. I've looked at CGEL (both hollow clauses and infinitival relative clauses). The only thing I got from CGEL is that the current sentence is not a hollow clause but an infinitive relative clause, and also that there is no infinitive relative clause shown in CGEL where a preposition at the end is left out simply because it's a preposition at the end. Hence, this question.

Comment: There's various constructions that are quite similar to each other, and that's basically what is confusing you (it seems to me). Consider: *"I have no ball", "I have no ball to play soccer", "I have no ball to play soccer with"* are all grammatical. Finite relatives and infinite relatives have something in common, and infinite relatives and hollow clauses have something in common, and then there's also infinitival purpose clauses. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) It's understanding how to parse and interpret those constructions properly that's important here, which includes figuring out the relativized element and the meaning of the hollow gap. Perhaps if this question was posted on the ELL site, then someone might be able to help you with it.

Comment: @F.E. Please post your answer here. I can't wait to see it. But I'll be waiting.

Comment: I've already recently posted a long, long, long answer on this EL&U site. It was to be a once-in-a-blue-moon sort of event. -- Supposedly I'm mostly posting answer-posts on ELL, about one per week. :)

Comment: Is the exemplary answer the one with 11 upvotes and 5 downvotes, the one with 6 upvotes and 2 downvotes, the one with 4 upvotes and 3 downvotes, the one with 2 upvotes and 1 downvote, the one with 1 upvote and 1 downvote (and a 150-point bounty), or the one with 0 upvotes and 0 downvotes? In seven days, all will be revealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, grammar is not the main issue; It is what people will understand by your statement.

> I have no reason to buy a bed.
>
> I have no inclination to buy a bed.
>
> I have no room to put a bed [in].
>
> I have no money to buy a bed [with].
>
> I know of no good shop to buy a bed [from].
>
> I have no family to buy a bed [for].
>
> I have no other furniture to put a bed [beside]. (this might be in response to a salesman saying "Here is a colourful bed which will add glamour to a bookshelf or a desk nearby")

Here, the first two statements do not require any word after "bed", while all the remaining can take a preposition.

These are all grammatically fine, but if contemporary folks can understand the statements without a preposition (the last word in square brackets) & if they think it is "pompous" to use that preposition, then drop it. If they do not understand the meaning or they feel that it sounds incomplete, then use the preposition. **My choice is to use the preposition, atleast where the meaning changes without it**.

Depending on whether the preposition is included or not, the two sentences (while being **grammatically correct**) will have two slightly **different meanings**, so most of my examples require the last word to completely convey the intended meaning. In the case of the fourth example, the preposition may be dropped, without much change in conveyed meaning, because money is **usually** used for buying things **with**. Hence, native speakers will have the tendency to drop it, I guess.

Comment: None of those examples with the preposition at the end sound pompous. But placing the preposition with its pronoun, e.g.  "I have no friend **with whom** to share a bed" can sound ‘pompous’ = very formal :) (It's the *whom* which many find objectionable/pompous nowadays)

Comment: @Prem: Good examples. Whether you want to call it grammar or something else, don't you think that there is a tendency amongst native speakers (at least AmE speakers) to drop the "with" from your fourth example, perhaps more so than to drop the prepositions from your third, fifth, sixth and seventh examples?

Comment: @Mari-LouA , agreed. I feel ,"with whom" probably sounds "pompous" because "whom" is itself going out of fashion, though that is only a guess.

Comment: @JK2 , agreed. Depending on weather the preposition is included or not, the two sentences (while being **grammatically correct**) will have two slightly **different meanings**, so most of my examples require the last word to completely convey the intended meaning. In the case of the fourth example, the preposition may be dropped, without much change in conveyed meaning, because money is usually used for buying things **with**. Hence, native speakers will have the tendency to drop it, I guess.

Comment: @Prem. Thanks for the comment, which is exactly what I meant by "an exception". So it seems that the meaning of "money" is the culprit that triggers such an exception. If so, that may be the answer I was looking for.  If you could edit your answer to incorporate what you said in your comment, I might as well award the bounty.

Comment: @JK2 , Done ; Incorporated comments into the answer.

Comment: @JK2 Just to be absolutely clear my stating that "to buy (something) with money" is "tautological" and underneath my answer [the comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242318/i-have-no-money-to-buy-a-bed-with/244298?noredirect=1#comment526912_244169) which I left (over a day ago)  that answered Araucaria's question does not satisfy you.

Comment: @JK2 Apologies for the terrible punctuation and phrasing above. It should be: *And the comment which I left, in reply to Araucaria's comment made a day ago, does not satisfy you?*

Answer (score 5):

In order to play a game of soccer you need ability and a ball, so it's quite natural to say:

(i) *I **can** play (soccer).* (ii) *I **can't** play (soccer)* (iii) *I can play soccer **with** a ball* (iv) *I **can't** play soccer **without** a ball.*

Likewise it is possible to use the modal *can* with the verb *buy*

(i) *I **can** buy.* (ii) *I **can't** buy* (note that we are speaking about the  ability to buy, no object is required, sentences (i) and (ii) stand on their own.) (iii) *I can buy **food***. (iv) *I can  buy food **with** money*. (v) I **can't** buy food **without** money

**to have no + object**

1. I have no money. [*to do with what?*]
2. I have no money **with which** to buy [*to buy what?*]
3. I have no money **with which** to buy food. [outdated]
4. I have no money to buy food **with**. [the same meaning as 3.]
5. I have no money to buy food. [grammatical]

To specify that you buy food *with* money is tautological. Can sentence 5 stand alone? Yes, it can. The positive sentence “I have money **with which** to buy food” is grammatical but it sounds very formal. By deleting “with which” we have a more modern sounding sentence:

6. I have money to buy food. [YES]

---

1. I have no ball [*to do with what?*]
2. I have no ball **with which** to play [*to play what?*]
3. I have no ball with which to play **soccer**. [outdated]
4. I have no ball to play soccer **with**. [modern]

Delete *soccer* and we're left with

5. I have no ball to play **with**

In #2. *which* refers to *ball*. If the object of the sentence was *friend* then *whom* could be used.

2. I have no friend **with whom** to play.

This is quite formal and today's native speakers may find it pompous-sounding and artificial. Nowadays, it is more common to hear:

5. I have no friend to play **with**.

delete *with* and we're left with

6. *I have no friend to play [?]

This sentence is incomplete. In positive sentences, we would not normally say

7. I have a friend to play.[NO]

   - What does the speaker need a friend for?
   - **To play** (soccer) **with**.
   - I have a friend **with whom** to play. [YES]
   - I have a friend to play **with**. [YES]
   - I have a friend **who** I play **with**. [YES]

This construction also holds true in the negative; therefore,  after the clause *I have no friend* we can insert *with whom* before the verb *to play* as in sentence  #2, or we add the preposition *with* at the end of the sentence as in #5.

The preposition *with* refers to the friend. You play *with* a friend. Similarly you can play soccer *with* a friend. You don't play *with* soccer; e.g. *I play with soccer. [NO] However, you play soccer *with* a ball. Here *with* tells us that a ball is *used* in order to play soccer. E.g. *I  write **with** a pen*. But I could also *write with* a pencil, biro, marker, penknife etc. If I have no pen, I say:

2. *I have no pen to write [*to do what?*]
3. *I have no pen to write **with***

In #2. the sentence sounds incomplete.

> **[with](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/with)**
>   **10**. a. By the means or agency of: eat with a fork; made us laugh with his jokes.

**EDIT**
In answer to Araucaria's comment “However - [I don't understand why to buy food with money is tautological](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242318/i-have-no-money-to-buy-a-bed-with/244298?noredirect=1#comment526903_244169), (i.e. why the ‘with’ is tautological), but to write with a pen is not. In standard British English, 4 and 5 are equally acceptable ...”

I gave the following explanation

> Why do you think “with money” is *not* tautological (maybe redundant would have been a better word) to say?

- I have money to buy food (with).
- I can buy food (with money).
- I can afford to buy food (with money).

The words in brackets do not add meaning to the sentence. The exchange of money is implied when we say ‘buy’.

Comment: You said: [To specify that you buy food with money is a bit tautological. Can sentence 5 stand alone? Yes, it can.] The only one question that I had was what makes it possible for sentence 5 to stand alone without "with" at the end. Where in your post am I supposed to find the answer to that one question?

Comment: I sincerely hope that this answer does *not* say the same thing as user78549!!!!! This answer is not completely wrong and self-contradictory. However - I don't understand why to by food *with* money is tautological, (i.e. why the *with* is tautological), but to write *with* a pen is not. In standard British Englishes 4 and 5 are equally acceptable - if anything 4 is preferable all other things being equal (though they're both ok).

Comment: @Araucaria Why do you think “*with* money” is not tautological (maybe redundant would have been a better word) to say? I have money to buy food (with). I can buy food (with money). I can afford to buy food (with money). The words in brackets do not add meaning to the sentence. The exchange of money is implied when we say ‘buy’. That's, in any case, how I see it. It's a bit over the top to say user78549's answer is *completely* wrong. But, if I understood your comment,  my answer might be a little wrong? :) :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's not the money being redundant, it's the *with* that I have a problem with. We use money to buy things with (it). We use pens to write things with (them). Why is the *with* redundant in one case but not in the other? Its the money and the pens which are the direct objects of the main verb *have* , so in any case, arguably it's the verbs in the infinitives themselves which are redundant :) Re completely*, well, you aren't misrepresenting a source in your post. You note that some sentences are a bit *outdated* - I'd say formal, but hey. You don't say (4) is *considered incorrect*.

Comment: I deleted my first comment because after a more careful reading, I no longer think I am paraphrasing user78549's answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: The "edit" you added at the end does not distinguish between omitting "with money" altogether and omitting "with" alone while "money" is still mentioned in the sentence. The reason for your answer not "satisfying me," as you put it under Prem's answer, is because the issue I'm interested in is not about whether to omit "with money" altogether but about whether to omit "with" alone while having "money" intact in the text.

Comment: @JK2 So why is my "I have money to buy food (with)." not pertinent?

Comment: @JK2 you can choose whatever answer you prefer, it's your bounty and its your prerogative but don't tell me I didn't address the point.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Sorry if I offended you. I didn't mean to. It's just that the way you lumped the three examples together doesn't clearly pinpoint the issue that I'm interested in. If you didn't have the last two examples and more focused on examples like the first one, I might have recognized your point with more ease.

Comment: I think the answer is straightforward. "Play **with**" is a *phrasal verb*, whereas "buy with" is NOT. In "play with", the "with" is a particle/preposition acting as *complement* of "play". So if you remove "with", the verb "play", and hence the whole sentence becomes incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer lies in verb transitivity.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitivity_%28grammar%29

"Buy" requires an object. With some pedantic exceptions, one cannot just walk into a store and "buy." One needs to "buy something."

On the other hand, "play" has ambitransitivity, which makes it fit in a lot more sentence structures.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_verb#Ambitransitivity

Consider:

I went to the store and bought. (this needs an object)
I went to the store and bought a piano.
I went to the store and played.
I went to the store and played a piano.
I went to the store and bought with a piano. (this makes no sense)
I went to the store and played with a piano.

Comment: I don't see where you're coming from. Really.

Comment: -1 for not responding to my comment.

Comment: If the property of the verbs used were the real culprit, the finite relative clause lacking 'with' in the case of the verb 'buy', as in (1), would have been grammatical. But it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your examples is an infinitival relative clause.
The analysis depends on what is the subject of that clause.

(1) If the antecedent "money" is subject, then "with" is wrong:
*I have no money to buy a bed.*

(2) If the matrix subject "I" is subject, and hence the anaphoric gap "[]" (linked to "money") is a complement, then "with" is obligatory:
*I have no money to buy a bed with [].*
This can also be expressed without a stranded preposition, using relative "which" as anaphor:
*I have no money with which to buy a bed.*

You can say this either way round because you can equally well say (1) money can buy me a bed or (2) I can buy a bed with money.  In contrast, a ball cannot play soccer, so cannot be subject of the infinitival clause "to play soccer", but only its oblique complement in "to play soccer with".

A related example is "This is the man to help", which is ambiguous depending on whether you read the anaphoric gap linked to the antecedent "man" as:
(1) subject [meaning *This is the man to help you*] or
(2) object [meaning *This is the man for you to help*].
Supplying a specific subject or object removes the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question is moot. I'd just keep things simple and omit "with" from *both* statements:

"I have no money to buy a bed."

"I have no ball to play soccer."

As long as the meaning is understood, less is more.

Comment: If less is more, why doesn't (1) work?

Answer (score -3):

## confusion

In the original question there was some confusion,

> why we omit with when we say... **grammatically**, it's the same as
>   "I have no ball to play soccer with". In this case, having with is
>   **correct**, while in the case of the first sentence, it **feels weird** to have *with* at the end of the sentence. Also, "I have no
>   time to study" and "I have no one to study with"... how would I
>   explain why we omitted with in the first sentence?

and one couldn't possible give a rational answer. OP was mixing, confusing the concepts of 'grammatical', 'correct' and 'feel weird, and in the last example he was asking why we don't say:

- "I have no time to study **with**"

what can one possibly answer? what has grammar got to do with an *absurd* concept/ proposition?

## more confusion

this question reports

> it **sounds better**... 
>   Indeed, the 'with' **feels redundant**
>    leaving out
>   'with' here would make it **ungrammatical** I have no ball to play with. As one of the answers in the quoted
>   question says, it may **be okay** to use 'with which'  Given that the version
>   without 'with which' **sounds right**, it might be argued that this
>   version with 'with which' may **be redundant** and thus as **unidiomatic** 
>   .. But native speakers seem to find
>   the former **grammatical**...
>   (1) I have no money I can buy a bed. (??).. 
>   (2) I have no money I can buy a bed with...
>   (3) I have no money with which I can buy a bed. Here, it seems clear
>   to me that 'with' cannot be omitted,

Again, what can one answer to this rambling? answer if it is grammatical, ungrammatical not ungrammatical, sounds/feels right, is or feels reduntant, is idiomatic or unidiomatic (whatever that means) or **is okay**? What does 'okay' mean: correct, incorrect, grammatical, that *feels* correct or not weird?:

> "Before jumping ... Citing a reference is not obligatory to get the
>   bounty, although I'd prefer one. - JK2"

What reference can one quote to affirm that a sentence *feels okay*, or is/feels redundant?, I ask!

Now, let's come to the:

## question

> Therefore, I'd say that the **idiomatic** "I have no money to buy a bed"
>   resisting with at the end is more of an **exception** in the sense that
>   corresponding finite relative clauses do **require** 'with' either at the
>   beginning or at the end of the clause, and that the corresponding
>   infinitive clause with 'which' requires 'with'.**What do you think triggers this exception?**
>   EDIT 
>   It may be worthwhile to note that the version with "with" is **not
>   ungrammatical:**
>
> I have no money to buy a bed with. Some native speakers might find
>   this version more **correct** -- if not more **common** -- than the one
>   lacking "with". -JK2

The question is not only confused, but loaded: he has already decided it is **an exception** and is asking what is the reason of that exception.

## answer

Now, it takes some time to digest this question, it seems to regard the difference between the 2 forms, the first of which is the exception, if I got it wrong he will correct me:

- I have no money to buy a bed (*idiomatic, an exception to the rule*)
- I have no money to buy a bed with (**not ungramatical**)

*Ellie Kesselman* replied that the correct form is: "*I have no money with which to buy a bed*." wasn't it enough?

*Mari-Lou* confirm this is correct, but, in her opinion, it sounds *formal* and prefers "I have no money to buy a bed (food). Which is correct, too. She does not directly answer the question, but we may infer from another example (I have no ball to play soccer with. [modern]) that she thinks that "I have no money to buy a bed with" sounds correct and 'modern', to boot.

*phaedrus*, *user78549*, *Andy ielding* etc., do not like that form. *"I suspect that when we depart from the resource/object during the act, we feel weird to use 'with' ". - phaedrus*

*Grammar has nothing to do with this*:  some thinks it is okay, and so does OP. I will not express my opinion because it is just an opinion and I'm sure that if it *ì*sounds weird* to me, it is not relevant or interesting.

I'll only reply to the question affirming that

- *I have no money to buy a bed (*idiomatic, an exception to the rule*)* is neither idiomatic nor an exception to *any rule* it is only a short  (elliptical) form of the formal canonical: "I have no money [with which]..
- that the second form requires a far more complex (*if not mirror-climbing*) canonical grammatical justification

**Update**

> I'd like to know if you think that you could readily omit prepositions
>   from Prem's 3rd-7th examples,.... and if you still think that Prem's 4th
>   example is not an **exception**, - JK2

I think I have identified the concept you are missing: [**register**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics))

The concept of 'grammatical' is different from the concept of 'appropriate', 'right', 'acceptable', 'sounds good/ okay', that's why I kept repeating it and I hope that after reading that article now you can understand.

What is 'grammatically *incorrect*' can be quite *acceptable*, can '*sound/be okay*':

- in different situations
- to a) people belonging to different areas, b) social classes, c) levels of education

Just to give you a *strong* example, if you are in a certain area, among a certain group of people:

- "I don't need **nobody**" sounds okay, as a *straw poll of six native speakers* will certify!

Conversely, what is *grammatically correct* is *not acceptable* in different situations. I suppose no examples are needed, as you surely know that the same *correct* proposition you say to your friends you *can't* say to your professor.

In addition to this complex situation, the very concept of *correct* changes with time, and a statement is true only *here and now*

If/ when you understand that, you'll understand what so many posters have told you. The state of the art, now, is that a preposition at the end is *correct* in a few cases. Outside that, the *context* and only the context can tell you if it sounds okay or not.

- "I have no bed to buy a bed [with]"

the preposition simply **should not be there*. Period. But, in a sitting-room, in a pub, or among low-educated people, it can be *anything*. Nobody can be blamed, except a teacher who teaches his/her students what is acceptable only in a pub.

In case it is not yet clear, I'll comply with your request, adding a last remark, and then I'll drop out of the discussion:

- examples 1, 2 do not require a preposition at all, I do not see why they are here: adding a preposition would be simply irrational, nothing to do with grammar,
- examples 3-7 are all alike, they have the **same structure**, so I can't see why you are singling it out, it is no exception. There is no difference in meaning, the preposition is redundant, useless as far as *meaning* is concerned. Therefore I, for one, see no reason why one should add something which is useless, especially when it is an infraction of *current grammatical standards*

Comment: Maybe you're right. I may be all confused about all this. But if I weren't, GreenRay, I wouldn't be here wasting my time and others' in the first place. Aren't those who are confused the ones who post questions? Anyway, those who post answers here that don't directly address the call of the question only add more confusion to the question.

Comment: @JK2, you are equivocating: "*Aren't... confused..t questions?* sure, but the question must make sense, must be *answerable*. You decide what you do not understand and ask a clear specific question, You cannot ask at the same time if a sentence is grammatical/idiomatic/unidiomatic/redundant or sounds okay. Also, you ask a question which is not loaded and allows the correct answer, and try to be serious and not mess around: *'how  can I play with a ball I don't have'*. If you have problems with English, ask someone to edit your question. If you update your post, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: You say I was being unclear in my earlier comment to your answer. And you say my question is not "answerable." You see, more than 7 people (used to be 10) voted my question to be showing research effort, and to be useful and clear. I guess that's above average. Moreover, as of now, no less than 5 people including yourself chose to post their answers. If it were unanswerable, why not just vote it down and move on? Or better yet, why don't you try editing the question yourself if you find the way it is presented confusing?

Comment: @JK2, you should decide if you want to argue or if you want help. I admire the persons who tried to answer this question [including myself :) ]. I'll be able to help you if you tell me what you want to know. If you have learned something from all these answers, (the current rules have been quoted), *radically* edit your post, give only a couple of sentences and ask exactly what is still unclear. Be careful not to mix two or more concepts. *Btw* : my answer didn't convince you? what else can one possible add?

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a rant at the OP. And a badly written one too.

Comment: @GreenRay, this might sound weird, but would you go over to Prem's answer and look at my comment there? In that comment, I actually asked a question that you might think is more answerable than the OP. If you find it answerable, please go ahead and add a comment there and answer the question there. I'd like to know if you think that you could readily omit prepositions from Prem's 3rd-7th examples, and if you still think that Prem's 4th example is not an exception in allowing the omission of the preposition more readily than others.

Comment: Quote from post: ***Fair enough!, why ask a question, then, why offer a bounty? You'd like everyone to agree, reply, maybe get a bounty? and if one disagrees is wrong or contradictory?I will not express my opinion because it is just an opinion and I'm sure that if it sounds weird to me, it is not relevant or interesting.*** This is not appropriate to put in your post. It's rude and disrespectful. Keep this kind of drivel in the comments (or just in your mind).

Comment: Note, it appears that the bounty was awarded to the user, formerly known as Green Ray, by their sockpuppet.